# Is it possible to get my bitcoin out of Strongcoin without paying the exorbitant transfer fee?

Tags: transactions, exchange-fees

I have Bitcoin held in Strongcoin's service, and want to transfer it out. The [Strongcoin FAQ](https://strongcoin.com/blog/frequently_asked_questions) (last updated 2011) says the transfer fee is 1% (which I'm prepared to put up with) with a minimum fee of 0.004BTC (which I am not). I've verified that it does intend to charge 0.004 BTC for the transfer.

My impression is that this minimum was set a long time ago when it was a small amount of money and never updated.

I think it's not a fair transfer fee and want to avoid paying it if at all possible. Is there any way around it? I'd be happy to pay a reasonable amount closer to 0.0005 BTC.

I know the [owner of Strongcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/293/ian-purton) uses this site (or at least has in the past) and I hope he can chip in here.

Comment: According to that FAQ you can export your private key. That should be enough to enable you to use a normal wallet (non-custodial) to "transfer it out" or otherwise take personal control of your own cash.

Comment: thanks @RedGrittyBrick however, though the FAQ does say that it's possible to get the private key, in reality I can't see any way to do that.